# R - dplyr/purrr - Create new columns from function of pairs of existing columns

Tags: r, dplyr, data-manipulation, purrr

I've run into a stumbling block with dplyr::mutate a few times in that I can't figure out how to create new columns based on a function (e.g., summing or anything else) that would create new columns based on all pairs of two input sets of columns. A partial demonstration is below:

```
#Input data
set.seed(100)
in_dat <- tibble(x1 = sample(x = c(1:10, NA_real_), size = 1000, replace = TRUE),
                 x2 = sample(x = c(1:10, NA_real_), size = 1000, replace = TRUE),
                 x3 = sample(x = c(1:10, NA_real_), size = 1000, replace = TRUE),
                 x4 = sample(x = c(1:10, NA_real_), size = 1000, replace = TRUE),
                 y1 = sample(x = c(1, 0, NA_real_), size = 1000, replace = TRUE),
                 y2 = sample(x = c(1, 0, NA_real_), size = 1000, replace = TRUE),
                 y3 = sample(x = c(1, 0, NA_real_), size = 1000, replace = TRUE),
                 y4 = sample(x = c(1, 0, NA_real_), size = 1000, replace = TRUE),
                 y5 = sample(x = c(1, 0, NA_real_), size = 1000, replace = TRUE),
                 y6 = sample(x = c(1, 0, NA_real_), size = 1000, replace = TRUE))

#Output data with 1 column pair; all pairs between x and y should be computed
out_dat_1col <- in_dat %>% 
  mutate(miss_x1y1 = if_else(is.na(x1) & is.na(y1), TRUE, FALSE))
```

This checks to see of pairs of x and y columns both have missing values and marks TRUE in the new column. This is only one pair though, and I'd like a way to do this for all pairs between x and y columns other than manually coding each of them in their own mutate line. I think purrr should be able to accomplish this, but I haven't figured out the proper syntax with the map variants or possibly reduce as well. I'm currently getting an error from both `map2_dfc` (to append the new columns on to the existing columns with `bind_cols`) and `reduce2` that `.x` (x variables) and `.y` (y variables) are not of consistent length, and I'm not sure how to circumvent this. Any thoughts are much appreciated.

```
#Produces error
out_dat <- in_dat %>% 
  bind_cols(map2_dfc(
    .x = in_dat %>% select(starts_with('x')),
    .y = in_dat %>% select(starts_with('y')),
    .f = ~if_else(is.na(.x) & is.na(.y), TRUE, FALSE)
  ))

Error: Mapped vectors must have consistent lengths:
* `.x` has length 4
* `.y` has length 6
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a short base R way to create the data frame using `lapply`, `sapply` and `mapply`:

```
all_cols <- lapply(in_dat, function(y) sapply(in_dat, function(x) is.na(y) & is.na(x)))
all_cols <- mapply(function(x, y) {colnames(x) <- paste(y, colnames(x), sep = "_"); x}, 
                   all_cols, names(all_cols), SIMPLIFY = FALSE)
df <- as_tibble(cbind(in_dat, do.call(cbind, all_cols)))
df
#> # A tibble: 1,000 x 110
#>       x1    x2    x3    x4    y1    y2    y3    y4    y5    y6 x1_x1 x1_x2 x1_x3 x1_x4
#>    <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <lgl> <lgl> <lgl> <lgl>
#>  1     3     7     2     5     1     1     0     1     0    NA FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE 
#>  2     7     5    10     3    NA     0    NA    NA     0    NA FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
#>  3     3     3     3     7     1     1    NA     1     1     1 FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
#>  4     7     3     1     8     1    NA     1     0    NA     1 FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE 
#>  5     5     2    10     7     0    NA    NA     0    NA     1 FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE 
#>  6     7     8    10     8    NA     1     1     1     1     1 FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE 
#>  7    10     8     3     5     0     1    NA     1     1     1 FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE 
#>  8     1    10     5    10     1    NA    NA     0     1     1 FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
#>  9     7     2     5     9    NA     0     0    NA     1     1 FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
#> 10     8     9     1     4     1    NA    NA     1    NA     0 FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
#> # ... with 990 more rows, and 96 more variables
```

The only problem being that you have also checked each row against itself, so to remove them you could do something like this:

```
df <- df[sapply(strsplit(names(df), "_"), function(x) {!any(duplicated(x))})]
```